# How to instantiate HttpEntity with a given Class type

Tags: java

I want to create an HttpEntity with a Class type I am passing. I am trying to do something like below:

```
    private <T> HttpEntity<clazz> createRequestEntity(String 
         cl, String co, String con, T body, Class<?> clazz) 
{
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.set(Constants.XCL, cl);
    httpHeaders.set(Constants.XCO, co);
    httpHeaders.set(Constants.XCON, con);

    HttpEntity<clazz> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, httpHeaders);
    return httpEntity;
}
```

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As you don't need the `clazz` type, it don't need to be part of the parameter. The code could be like this:

```java
private <T> HttpEntity<T> createRequestEntity(String cl, String co, String con, T body)
{
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return new HttpEntity<>(body, httpHeaders);
}
```

Comment: Thanks TKJohn. I got confused around T and Class<?> :)